# Is it better to add a transcript of a non-completed degree for a master's degree admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

Im getting my degree this year (in june presumably) in physics. And while I was getting it I was at the same time getting a degree in mathematics. (By degree I mean completing undergraduate studies in both of those things, I'm from Spain and I'm not sure about the equivalence...).

Now, I dedicated to physics full-time and by the time I will have finished physics (june as I said) I will have approximately 50% of my degree in maths. Independently of the maths degree, next year I will apply to some post-graduate studies outside of my country and I would like to know if I should apply with my physics degree or if it would make any significant (and positive) change in my application to say that I've also been studying half a degree on maths and include a transcript of what I've studied in that degree.

The problems is what I commented on BPND answer, plus the fact that transcripts are 30€ plus 80€ the sworn translation, and if I can keep expenses down, that's a plus. My question is if the difference by including it will be positive. The average grades are 9.24 (GPA 3.9) and 9.2 (GPA 3.82) in physics and maths respectively, out of 10.

The GPAs were calculated with some online converter I found, using all the subjects and the credits for each one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many universities will demand a full transcript of your academic history, so, in that case, you will need to attach both (or a combined) transcript(s) to your application.

Even if they only ask for the transcript of your main studies, you might want to attach the transcript for the math lectures and exercises. Especially in this case, where math acts perfectly as a supporting discipline for a phyiscs major.

Comment: Ok, the universities I'm checking out doesn't explicitly require a full academic history, they just require having a BA degree in order to start a master degree, so I could apply with my physics degree. My only worry is that my average score in the maths degree is a little bit lower than the physics one (9.24 and 9.2 in physics/math respectively) out of ten. And I'm worried that a lower score could lower my possibilities of being accepted. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I edited the first post, another issue would be the money it costs to take transcripts, although that's not the main problem... I just would like to know if that grade difference would be negative (some online conversor to GPA x/4 gives a 3.9 for physics and 3.83 for maths)

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** You should apply with **both** of your degrees unless you did poorly during your math studies. However, the honest applicant would apply with both no matter what, as both of these degrees are part of your academic history.

**Reason:** Academic institutions want to see you have accomplished a lot. The more you appear to have done, the more likely you will be to get in, as long as you did well during you math studies. Furthermore, as was stated previously, universities often require a full transcript.

Comment: My first post has my scores for both studies. I didn't do poorly, just a little bit worse (9.24/10 in physics and 9.2/10 in maths). If more studies is better than that little difference, then that's what I want to know. Another issue is that my math degree is unfinished.

Comment: Based on that differe,ce I would think you should submit both. People apply with unfinished degrees all of the time, think of people in their final year of undergrad applying. You should include both unless you do not plan on finishing the second degree.

Comment: Even if he does not plan to finish his second degree, it shows improved knowledge in math, and with math being a good supporting science for physics, it makes it a good idea to include that specific transcript in an application (in MY opinion).

Comment: @BPND I don't plan on finishing it this year, and so I will apply with both unfinished degrees but only the physics one will be finished once the next academic year starts. Ok, thank you both, I will use both, then.